# Literature values for NaCl Eutectic - Calculating the eutectic

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, phase, eutectic

For the NaCl eutectic I've seen two values widely used:

23.3wt% NaCl - James G. Speight: Lange's Handbook of Chemistry 2017)

5.1 M NaCl (Marion + Kargel 2008 - Cold Aqueous Planetary Geochemistry with FREZCHEM)

both of which are at about -21C.

Am I being silly - these values aren't the same (they're both at atmospheric pressure)?

Is my maths right?
[23.3wt%=3.99M and 5.1M= 29.8wt%]

Comment: What density are you using for the comparison?

Comment: I've just been reading off quote values, so would a 5.1M solution, corrected for density at -21C, be 23.3wt%?t

Comment: I guess it would.

Comment: I've found that the specific gravity of a 23.3 wt% solution is 1.179. How would I use this to work out the molarity of the solution

Comment: What is molarity, really?

Comment: So in this text, it says 5.175 Molal is the eutectic, (which should be equal to 23.3wt %). So this requires a 23.3wt% solution to have a density of 1.298 at -21.3 C, which is way off 1.179.